# Defining a homomorphism of $R$-modules: trouble in proof

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $A$ be a left $R$-module and $G$ an abelian group. Make $\rm{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}(R,G)$ into a left $R$-module with 
$$(r.\varphi )(\lambda)=\varphi(\lambda r).$$
Define a map from $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}(A,G)$ to $\mathrm{Hom}_{R}(A,\rm{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}(R,G))$ as follows:

given $\psi\in \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}(A,G)$ define $\psi':A\rightarrow \rm{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}(R,G)$ by 
$$\psi'(a):R\rightarrow G, \hskip5mm \psi'(a)(\lambda)=\psi(\lambda a).$$
It is easy to show that $\psi'$ is additive homomorphism. My trouble is in proving that it is $R$-a module homomorphism.

$$\psi'(ra)(\lambda)=\psi(\lambda(ra))=\psi((\lambda r)a)=\psi'(a)(\lambda r).$$
I couldn't proceed here after to prove that $\psi'$ is $R$-module homomorphism. How to proceed?

Comment: You are right; I had confused the terminology in definition and in theorem; perhaps, now it is corrected as aboe; is it right?

Comment: Note that to make $\text{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}(R,G)$ into a left $R$-module you define $r\theta$ by  $(r\theta)(r')=\theta(r'r)$

Comment: This means that $\psi'(a)(\lambda r) = (r \psi'(a))(\lambda)$.

Comment: Now perhaps we can complete: $\psi'(a)(\lambda r) = (r.\psi'(a))(\lambda)$, is it right?

Comment: Maybe your confusion is that $\text{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}(A,G)$ is a right $R$-module while $\text{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}(R,G)$ is a left $R$-module.

Comment: Oh, Nex, you already stated this. Now it is clear. Thanks for stating mistakes and clarification. (You may post it as answer; it is clear now.)